# how to find length of a pair with out considering dot and elements after dot in scheme language?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I found the length of a whole pair but i am not able to find length of a pair excluding dot and elements after dot. any suggestion is appreciated.

```
(define (paircount seq)
  (cond ((null? seq) 0)
    ((not (pair? seq)) 1)
    (else (+ (paircount (car seq))
             (paircount (cdr seq))))))

         input: (paircount '(a b c d . e))
         output : 5
         desired output : 4 (considering only a b c d but not 'e')
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just change the `((not (pair? seq)) 1)` to `((not (pair? seq)) 0)`.

Answer (score -2):

A normal scheme list takes the form

```
(a . b . c . d . e . null)
```

Each item in the list is a pair containing your value as the first element and another pair as the second, except the final pair which contains null.

In your case, the second element of the final pair is a value that is neither a pair nor null. It sounds like all you have to do is exclude this item.

```
(define (paircount seq)
  (cond ((null? seq) 0)
        ((pair? seq) (+ 1 (paircount (cdr seq))))
        ; The else case excludes the second element
        ; of the final pair
        (else 0)))
```

Here's a little bonus. As written, your function is not tail recursive. For each element in the list, there will be a separate stack frame, so for really long lists you might run out of memory. Try this way instead:

```
(define (paircount seq)
  (define (foo s accum)
    (cond ((null? s) accum)
          ((pair? s) (foo (cdr s) (+ 1 accum)))
          (else accum)))
  (foo seq 0))
```

Notice how your version first calls itself, then adds the results. This version first does the addition, then calls foo with the sum.

Finally, is it your intention to count the number of elements of a list of lists? If you don't know how deeply the lists are nested, then you cannot distinguish a pair that should be interpreted as a list from a pair that should be interpreted as just an element that happens to be a pair.

Comment: I think you mean (a . (b .  (c . (d . (e . null)))))